# repeatrows based on second frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to ask for your support. I tried many things, without success.

Suppose you have two different frames, a long frame (LF) (high number of rows) and a short frame (SF) (low number of rows), see example

```
SF=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3],"col2":[4,5,6]})
LF=pd.DataFrame({"col_long":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]})
```

I need to loop through the values of a specific column from the short frame, let's say we take "Test col2" and concat along axis 1 both frames. I have a solution which works, like this:

```
EMPTY_FRAME=pd.DataFrame()
SF=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3],"col2":[4,5,6]})
LF=pd.DataFrame({"col_long":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]})


for i in range(len(SF.index)):
    LF["col1"]=SF["col1"].values[i]
    LF["col2"]=SF["col2"].values[i]
    EMPTY_FRAME=EMPTY_FRAME.append(LF)

LF=   col_long  col1  col2
0          1     1     4
1          2     1     4
2          3     1     4
3          4     1     4
4          5     1     4
5          6     1     4
6          7     1     4
7          8     1     4
8          9     1     4
9         10     1     4
10        11     1     4
0          1     2     5
1          2     2     5
2          3     2     5
3          4     2     5
4          5     2     5
5          6     2     5
6          7     2     5
7          8     2     5
8          9     2     5
9         10     2     5
10        11     2     5
0          1     3     6
1          2     3     6
2          3     3     6
3          4     3     6
4          5     3     6
5          6     3     6
6          7     3     6
7          8     3     6
8          9     3     6
9         10     3     6
10        11     3     6
```

but gets pretty confusing since I have many columns inside the SF and thus I might forget some columns. So the question: Is there any chance have the following solution in a better and shorter way?

I really would be grateful if you guys have an idea how I could further improve my code

Comment: cross join `out = LF.assign(k=1).merge(SF.assign(k=1),on='k').drop('k',1)` ?

Comment: It's not exactly what I need. I need the output exactly the way I highlighted. I did copy paste on your code but the output is not the desired output

Comment: you mean the order of the first column? do you also want to retain the index?

Comment: I have rolled back the edit to the previous question so both the question and the answer makes sense to future readers. Please let me know if otherwise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can cross join with reindex to retain the order:

```
out = (SF.assign(k=1).merge(LF.assign(k=1),on='k').drop('k',1)
   .reindex(columns=LF.columns.union(SF.columns,sort=False)))

out.index = out['col_long'].factorize()[0] #if required
```

---

```
print(out)

    col_long  col1  col2
0          1     1     4
1          2     1     4
2          3     1     4
3          4     1     4
4          5     1     4
5          6     1     4
6          7     1     4
7          8     1     4
8          9     1     4
9         10     1     4
10        11     1     4
0          1     2     5
1          2     2     5
2          3     2     5
3          4     2     5
4          5     2     5
5          6     2     5
6          7     2     5
7          8     2     5
8          9     2     5
9         10     2     5
10        11     2     5
0          1     3     6
1          2     3     6
2          3     3     6
3          4     3     6
4          5     3     6
5          6     3     6
6          7     3     6
7          8     3     6
8          9     3     6
9         10     3     6
10        11     3     6
```

Comment: hey anky_91,
thank you very much. It is really very close to the solution I am a looking. Again thanks. But I need to loop through the specific column. I updated my problem to be clearer. Would appreciate if you could have a look

Comment: @SMS the solution does exactly what you asked for initially. You should not iterate through a dataframe unless absolutely necessary. Also you should have asked a new question as your question was answered.